# How can I make certain c++ features required in my cmake project?

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, c++14

I'm writing on the `CMakeLists.txt` for my c++14 project. I want other users to be able to build my project, but their compiler might no support the c++14 features I am using. How can I get cmake to print an error message, if the compiler does not support my c++14 code?

I found the `target_compile_features` [command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html), which seems to do the right job. However, I am not sure how to use it correctly...

Is this right?

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
project(myproject VERSION 1.0.0
                  LANGUAGES CXX)
add_executable(myproject src/main.cpp)
target_compile_features(myproject PRIVATE cxx_auto_type)
...
```

Comment: While the answer is good, the question seems to be not. You say "... I don't really know what the right ones are. Which ones should I use for my project?", but you don't specify for **what exact purpose** you need the flags. You answer would fit for Documentation pages on Stack Overflow, but they have gone. Note, that Q/A (Question/Answer) format of Stack Overflow doesn't fit for every useful information. You may create a blog, however.

Comment: Hmm... I only started using Stack Overflow recently, so I don't know much about the conduct. What would you suggest? Rephrase the question? Do something else? A blog might be an idea, but I'm not really interested in creating one. Or is there some blog functionality in Stack Overflow?

Comment: No, as far as I know, Stack Overflow has no its own blog functionality. Rephrasing the question... I am unsure that it is possible to ask the question, which fits both for Stack Overflow rules and for given answer. Would I a developer, I would ask "My code uses c++11 features <A>, <B>, and <C>. I know that not all compilers support them. How to check that these features are supported in CMake?". So answer would be "Use `target_compile_features` with following arguments: ...". And at the end of the answer you may describe other features, supported by CMake.

Comment: You may also ask on [meta] about possible improvements of the given question. Such a way you may collect more ideas (and, possibly, great ones). In that case, however, be ready to "meta effect" - given question will attract much more views than now and more users could mark it, both positive and negative.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure if I want to ask Meta yet... However, I tried some rephrasing. How about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I think this is a common question, I will answer it myself:

While the general usage is right, you need to tweak the cmake code, if you are writing a library:

```
target_compile_features(myproject INTERFACE cxx_auto_type)
```

Furthermore, you need to add more features depending on what you are using. This can be done by simply listing them all:

```
target_compile_features(myproject INTERFACE cxx_auto_type
                                            cxx_static_assert
                                            ...)
```

## CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES

A list of possible values can be found in the cmake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html). However, I find the short sentences and links to the c++ standard not really helpful. I will therefore try to give a description of what feature each option encompasses.

I want to explain all of the options on the list, but this quite some time to write... Thus, I will begin with features I find useful or interesting, but will try adding more later. If anyone wants to add those I didn't come to post yet, I would be thankful as well.

I will link the same c++ standard documents as in the original, but I will also provide a link to the corresponding [cppreference](https://cppreference.com/) page and a small coding example if necessary.

### cxx_auto_type

[Auto type deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) was introduced in c++11 with [N1984](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1984.pdf). It allows users to write the `auto` keyword in all cases, were the compiler can deduce the result type automatically. The actual type does not have to be given anymore.

For example:

```
auto i = 0; //it is clear that we want an int here
auto d = 1.45; //it is clear that we want a double here
...
```

### cxx_binary_literals

[Binary literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) were introduced in c++14 with [N3472](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3472.pdf). They allow to write values in binary form, in addition to the existing hexa-decimal literals.

Binary literals are marked by either `0b` or `0B` in front of the binary value:

```
0B1000 == 8 //true
0b1001 == 9 //true
```

### cxx_deleted_functions

[Deleted functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) were introduced in c++11 with [N2346](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2346.htm). They allow users to explicitly delete certain operators and member functions inside a class. If the program would access any of the deleted functions, the code will not compile:

```
struct no_default_constructor {
    no_default_constructor() = delete; //the default constructor is deleted
    no_default_constructor(int value) : ...
    ...
};
```

Thus, a default construction is not possible, but another one might be.

```
no_default_constructor object = no_default_constructor(); //this will not compile
no_default_constructor object = no_default_constructor(2); //this will
```

### cxx_explicit_conversions

[Explicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) were added in c++11 with [N2437](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2437.pdf). They allow to specify class conversion to be explicit, meaning that no implicit conversion is possible.

For example:

```
struct flag {
    bool is_set;
    explicit operator bool() const { return is_set; }
};
```

This class cannot be converted implicitly to bool, but an explicit conversion is still possible:

```
void print_birthday_message(flag user_has_birthday) {
    bool has_birthday = user_has_birthday; //this is not possible
    bool has_birthday = bool(user_has_birthday); //but this is fine
    ...
}
```

### cxx_final

The [final keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) was introduced in c++11 with [N2928](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2928.htm), [N3206](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3206.htm), and [N3272](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3272.htm). It allows class designers to prevent users overwriting virtual functions, or member functions.

The `final` keyword has to be written at the end of virtual functions, to prevent additional overwriting:

```
struct Base { 
    virtual void function();
};
struct A : Base {
    void function() final; //overwrite Base::function and make it the final overwrite
};
struct B : A {
    void function() override; //this is not possible, as function was already marked final inside A
};
```

The `final` keyword has to be at the end of a derived classes name, to prevent overwriting:

```
struct Base {};
struct A final : Base {}; //struct A is now final
struct B : A {}; //this is not possible, as A was already marked final
```

### cxx_noexcept

The [noexcept keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) was introduced in c++11 with [N3050](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3050.html). It allows to mark functions, operators and constructors. If these are marked `noexcept`, they guaranty that no exceptions are thrown when they are invoked. Furthermore the "noexceptness" can be tested by the `noexcept(f)` function.

### cxx_raw_string_literals

[Raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) were introduced in c++11 with [N2442](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2442.htm). They allow to write arbitrary characters into a string without using escape characters.

Raw strings take the form `R"delimiter(raw_characters)delimiter"` with `delimiter` being an arbitrary name (following c++s naming standards). A common case is to use them for inputting scripting code directly in c++. Plus, with the `delimiter` being ignored by the compiler, using it to give the IDE a hint at the scripting language.

For example:

```
const char* code = R"chaiscript(
    print("Hello World")
)chaiscript";
```

### cxx_strong_enums

[Strongly typed enums](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) were introduced in c++11 with [N2347](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2347.pdf). They allow to set the type of an enum in a way, which prevents bugs with enums being automatically converted into other types.

Strongly types enums use the `enum class name` syntax. For example:

```
enum class colours {
    cyan = 0,
    red = 1,
    green = 2,
};
```

This makes accidental conversions impossible:

```
int color_index = colours::green; //this conversion is not allowed!
int color_index = int(colours::green); //explicit casts are still okay
```

### cxx_trailing_return_types

[Trailing return types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) were introduced in c++11 with [N2541](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2541.htm). They allow to define the return type of a function afterits parameters list:

```
auto greet() -> void {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

Trailing return types are useful in the AAA (Almost Always Auto) programming style, and in cases where the return type is complicated, or in template functions were it might depend on the input types.

### cxx_unicode_literals

[Unicode literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) were introduced in c++11 with [N2442](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2442.htm). They allow the user to directly input unicode characters into c++ without using unicode escape characters. (`\n`, ... still have to be escaped.)

They take the form `u8"(characters)"`. Were `u8` can be replace to change the underlying data type:

```
const char* utf8 = u8"(characters)";
const char16_t* utf16 = u"(characters)";
const char32_t* utf32 = U"(characters)";
```

### cxx_user_literals

[User literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) were introduced in c++11 with [N2765](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2765.pdf). They allow users to write custom type shortcuts and custom type conversions.

User literals are defined with the `operator ""`. For example a conversion from degrees to radians can be written like:

```
constexpr double operator "" _degrees(double value) {
    return value*3.14/180.;
}
```

The value is obtained by:

```
double theta = 90_degrees; //==1.57
```